# How to start processes in order?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a simple code for preparing and running processes:

```py
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.map(check_url, range(0, 240000)
```

This is necessary to verify the existence of pages on the site, for example site.com/298 - exists, site.com/17 - not exists. And so I need to check 240,000 pages.
The problem is that when you run a script, the range() gives values not in order, i.e. I see in the output:

```
Page found: 26545
Page not found: 1523
Page found: 45
Page found: 9
Page found: 4568
Page not found: 256
....
```

I tried to use the prepared list instead of the range:

```py
urls = [i for i in range(0, 240000)]
```

When I printed it out, I saw a list of numbers in order, but the processes still continue to start out of order.
How can I make processes run in order?

UPD: could it be that my solution can check the same page twice or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of Pool.map is to separate the tasks and let them do it separately (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map). If you want to feed the data in order you need to use a send the data in order, i.e.:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep
import random

def f(x):
    worker_name = mp.current_process().name
    print(f"[{x}] by {worker_name}")#start
    timetosleep=random.randrange(10)/10
    sleep(timetosleep) 
    print(f"-[{x}] by {worker_name}")#done
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Init")
    with mp.Pool(processes=16) as p:
        for i in range(10):
            p.apply_async(f, (i,))
        p.close()
        p.join()
    print("Done")
```

gives the output:

```
Init
[0] by SpawnPoolWorker-4
[1] by SpawnPoolWorker-2
[2] by SpawnPoolWorker-1
[3] by SpawnPoolWorker-3
[4] by SpawnPoolWorker-5
[5] by SpawnPoolWorker-6
[6] by SpawnPoolWorker-7
[7] by SpawnPoolWorker-8
[8] by SpawnPoolWorker-10
-[7] by SpawnPoolWorker-8
[9] by SpawnPoolWorker-8
-[5] by SpawnPoolWorker-6
-[2] by SpawnPoolWorker-1
-[0] by SpawnPoolWorker-4
-[9] by SpawnPoolWorker-8
-[4] by SpawnPoolWorker-5
-[8] by SpawnPoolWorker-10
-[6] by SpawnPoolWorker-7
-[3] by SpawnPoolWorker-3
-[1] by SpawnPoolWorker-2
Done
```

As you see, the processes are started with order but each takes different time to complete. If you need to complete in order then multiprocessing is not an option because you cannot guarantee that.

Comment: This also does not work for a large range. I ran a script with a range of 240000 and immediately the same output: Page exists: 7500 Page not exists: 32500 Page not exists: 0 and so on

Comment: The processes starts sequentially but as I said, you cannot guarantee that they will finish sequentially because every task takes different time. I don't know why you want the output inorder.

Comment: I have a process limit Pool(24). How does the process that should go ~ 32500 is almost completed first?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python documentation on Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) you can see the signature for 'map':

```
 map(func, iterable[, chunksize])

    A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.

    This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.
```

Your jobs are submitted in parallel, meaning they're not guaranteed to execute in sequence. If you need the site polled sequentially, parallelization may not be optimal, and you might consider a for loop to guarantee sequential behavior.

Comment: How i can do this with for loop? Can u please show example for my function.